# Rollback a pandas to_sql() operation if any error occurs

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I want to do a roll-back of a `df.to_sql` if any error occur, but I cannot find the base exceptions that `to_sql`-errors inherits from.

From [sqlalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.exc.SQLAlchemyError) all its errors inherit from `sqlalchemy.exc.SQLAlchemyError` but I don't know if `SQLAlchemyError` inherits from `BaseException`, `Exception` or something else.

I would assume that I'm safe if I catch `SQLAlchemyError` and `Exception`?

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

engine = create_engine()

with engine.connect() as conn:
    tran = conn.begin()
    
    try:
      df.to_sql("table", conn, index=False, if_exists="append")

      
    except: (SQLAlchemyError,Exception): #Want to capture all errors
      tran.rollback()
      print("Shiat broke down ...")
```

Comment: actually according to documentation all user-defined exceptions should derive from Exception. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html, so catching just Exception should cover your case.

Comment: That was my though but "should" and "is" are two completely different things, so it might be that SQLAlchemy didn't inherit from Exception

Comment: You are right:) Then, according to sqlalchemy doc (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/exceptions.html) all remaining should inherit from sqlalchemy.exc.SQLAlchemyError, except those from DBAPI, which inherit from sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `with engine.begin()` (instead of `with engine.connect()`) to handle the transaction for you. The block will automatically rollback if an error occurs, otherwise it will commit.

For example, this code

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

connection_url = (
    "mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger^5HHH@192.168.0.199/test"
    "?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
)
engine = sa.create_engine(
    connection_url,
    echo=True,
)
cause_error = False

table_name = "thing"
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {table_name}")
    conn.exec_driver_sql(
        f"CREATE TABLE {table_name} (id int primary key, txt varchar(50))"
    )
    if cause_error:
        conn.exec_driver_sql(
            f"INSERT INTO {table_name} (id, txt) VALUES (1, 'xyz')"
        )

df = pd.DataFrame([(1, "foo"), (2, "bar")], columns=["id", "txt"])
try:
    with engine.begin() as conn:
        df.to_sql(table_name, conn, if_exists="append", index=False)
        print(">>> All good.")
except Exception as e:
    print(">>> Something went wrong!")
```

shows this in the log

```
2022-02-01 10:45:01,835 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO thing (id, txt) VALUES (?, ?)
2022-02-01 10:45:01,835 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00053s] ((1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'))
>>> All good.
2022-02-01 10:45:01,860 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

However, if we use `cause_error = True` then the log contains

```
2022-02-01 10:53:29,385 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO thing (id, txt) VALUES (?, ?)
2022-02-01 10:53:29,385 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00046s] ((1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'))
2022-02-01 10:53:29,423 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
>>> Something went wrong!
```

Answer (score -1):

You could have looked into the source code with a few clicks [SQLAlchemyError](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/d6046f5fcf3732df1a8a08274501efcffc6253f2/lib/sqlalchemy/exc.py#L67).

[image]

Comment: Yes, I could've. But if I could find it, I wouldn't have had to ask the question. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @CutePoison no worries, next time just head over to their github page and poke around a bit. This is one of the advantages of open source projects in the end. :)